# How do i replicate this effect in React Three Fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've been using three.js for a while now and decided to move to react-three. for my first project I decided to replicate this effect I found on codepen: https://codepen.io/chriscourses/pen/aZRzOM since the  code is not too complicated I just need to offset the vertices of a PlaneGeometry over time to resemble the waves of a lowpoly ocean.

The problem comes from the react three library using a `PlaneBufferGeometry` compared to the `PlaneGeometry` used by the original implementation in plain JS. meaning that i do not have access to vertices information.
I've been able to work around this by updating the `geometry.attributes.position.array`

original:

```
geometry.vertices.forEach(function(vertice) {
    vertice.x += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
    vertice.y += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
    vertice.z += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
    vertice.dx = Math.random() - 0.5;
    vertice.dy = Math.random() - 0.5;
    vertice.randomDelay = Math.random() * 5;
});

for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setStyle( baseColor );
    geometry.faces[ i ].baseColor =  baseColorRGB;    
}
```

my implementation:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array.length; i += 3){
    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[i]     += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4  // x
    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[i + 1] += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4  // y
    mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[i + 2] += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4  // z
}
// can't access .dx, .dy, .randomDelay, and .faces
```

i'm struggling to find a way to update the geometry dx, dy, randomDelay, faces values since i cannot find them anyway in the `PlaneBufferGeometry`.

Here's my question:
how do i replicate the effect in react three? is there no way for me to use a plain PlaneGeometry?